# jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I downloaded jQuery UI 1.10.3.
And it comes with an older version of jQuery which is 1.9.1.
And I have a later version of jQuery: 1.10.2.
But jQuery UI seems does not like to work with 1.10.2...
Is there anyway to make it works?
Or I should just live with it..

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!--
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
-->
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
</script>
<script src = song_Selector.js>
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {

        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 50
        });
    });

</script>


<body>

    <p id="demo">Click the button to do something.</p>
    <button onclick="draw_Progress_Bar ()">Try it</button>

    <h2 class="demoHeaders">Progress Bar</h2>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>

</body>
```

Codes are above, without the `<html>` tag.

Comment: It should work...I noticed your other scripts are in your `js` directory, and your `1.10.2` script was not, is this correct?

Comment: @tymeJV yes it is correct that they are not in same folder... thats the problem? (Trying..) Didn't work..

Comment: What about the console, do you see any errors?

Comment: Actually I haven't know there is a console window when I was trying to mix together >_<b.. sry.. (i know it now.. I just stepped into this hole yesterday..)

Comment: It's your best friend. On Chrome, just hit F12 and select "Console" from the tabs.

Comment: I leanred to use Ctrl+Shift+C @_@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are loading the script, you've forgotten the end tags, and you've also forgotten your `<head>` tags if this is the whole document:

```
<!-- <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> -->
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script src = song_Selector.js></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 50
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <p id="demo">Click the button to do something.</p>
    <button onclick="draw_Progress_Bar ()">Try it</button>

    <h2 class="demoHeaders">Progress Bar</h2>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
</body>
```

What happened was actually the following when you uncommented jQuery 1.10.2:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
</script>
```

As any text inside a `<script>` tag is ignored with an `src` attribute set and will not be parsed, this will not be loaded.

Before, it would have worked fine as it would have simply been the following:

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js">
    </script>
</script>
```

... with the text inside the tag being ignored, as there is a `src` attribute (with this having no effect).

Comment: Thank you, noticed that... but i decide to drop JQuery UI and do my things in a 'stupid' but easier way.. I'll catch on that later.. =) Thanks, again..

Comment: Tried.. not working =(   I Actually already added the ending tag after I post this..   Found it.. I also commented out the Progress Bar code... mind blured @_@... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you can this by function load script

```
    function loadscript(url){
var doc = document.getelementbytagname("head");
var script = document.createlement("script") ; 
script.url = script
}
```

Comment: "you can this"? Anyway, i'll try it =)

Comment: You know that JavaScript is case-sensitive? Also you are missing characters in the function names. `getelementbytagname` should be `getElement` **`s`** `byTagName` and `createlement` should be `creat` **`e`** `Element`.

Comment: @FelixKling I will get it =) sometimes that can be troublesome (C&P and it didn't work lol), but... thanks anyway.. =D